# NodeJS connect to Java Mongo Driver

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, web-applications, protocols

In my project, I wanna use NodeJs as Server Front-end to deal with each connection and Java as Back-end server to manipulate MongoDB and do some machine learning jobs. However, I wonder: How can i make applications in server-side communicate with each other(NodeJs and Java in this case)? And more specific, What protocol should i use (I rather want it to be light-weight in term of message transport and long-living socket connection to reduce TCP low-start?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider running a TCP listener on the main application on the server side, that will be listening for incoming commands or data. And every application should connect the main one. I remember using such a solution in one of my projects and I've used `socket.io` library for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you. @KiraSan : You mean i should create a 'socket.io' application acts like middle of back-end and front-end? Do you have any solution to connect directly without using any middle? Thank you again.